# Xtext and Plugin: get EObject and return the first 10 chars written in the file

Tags: eclipse, plugins, xtext

I am writing plugin for my DSL language I wrote in xtext.

In my plugin I go over all the variable in the XtextResource of the current file like this:

```
  public void calculateVarsNamesList(XtextResource resource) {

  EObject content = resource.getContents().get(0);
  EList<EObject> ListOfEObject = content.eContents();

  for (int i=0; i < ListOfEObject.size(); i++){
       if (ListOfEObject.get(i) instanceof Var){
          Var v = (Var) ListOfEObject.get(i);
          String name = v.getName();
          if (name == null){
          // ***I want to get the first 10 chars of v (like it's written in the file)***
           }
      }}}
```

How I can do what I wrote in the comment? thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the NodeModelUtils. The class gives you access to the underlying node model that keeps the trace to the original file.